# Generate a pronounceable word

Tags: code-golf, random, natural-language, generation

The challenge is simple:

### generate a word.

Specifications:

- Word must be pronounceable.

  - This is defined as "alternating between a consonant and a vowel."
  - A consonant is one of the following letters: `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz`
  - A vowel is one of the following letters: `aeiouy`
- Word must be randomly generated.
- Words must be able to contain every consonant and vowel. (You can't just use `bcdf` for consonants and `aei` for vowels.)
- Word must contain 10 letters.
- Shortest code (in character count) wins.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11215/alien-name-generator

Comment: @JanDvorak Okay... what does that have to do with this?

Comment: With [this xkcd strip](http://xkcd.com/221/) in mind, the program `echo buxitiwymu` technically conforms to the specification. I assure you, I generated the word randomly:P

Comment: @AardvarkSoup "Words must be able to contain every consonant and vowel"

Comment: `y` is a vowel !?

Comment: Would something like this be allowed ? alert('abecidof'+'uy'[Math.round(Math.random())]+'ghijklmnpqrstvwxz'[Math.round(Math.random()*19)]);

Comment: @Kartik depends on the context, in 'yes' it's a consonant, in 'why' it's a vowel, but this would make it impossible to define a pronounceable word as alternating between vowels and consonants, eg. yyyyyyyy would be a valid word.

Comment: @Ragnagord No, it won't. But, `yyyyyyyyyy` would.

Comment: I actually made a generator on Scratch a while back. It had specific rules for when you can treat `y` as a vowel, where you can use `q` and `x`, and when you can use two-letter combinations like `ng` or `ea`

Comment: Similar to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/199139/write-some-random-english

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 32 characters

```
['aeiouy'.123,97>^]5*{.,rand=}%+
```

Run it [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=WydhZWlvdXknLjEyMyw5Nz5eXTUqey4scmFuZD19JSs%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 9):

## COBOL, 255

So I'm learning COBOL at the moment. Used this question as some practice. Tried to golf it.

It's 255 without the leading whitespace, and 286 bytes with.

For what it's worth, this runs in Microfocus COBOL for VS2012, and I have no idea if it will run anywhere else.

```
       1 l pic 99 1 s pic x(26) value'aeiouybcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz' 1 r
       pic 99 1 v pic 9 1 q pic 99. accept q perform test after varying
       l from 1 by 1 until l>9 compute v=function mod(l,2) compute r=1+
       function random(q*l)*5+v*15+v*5 display s(r:1)end-perform exit
```

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 81

```
from random import*
print''.join(map(choice,["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz","aeiouy"]*5))
```

Good luck pronouncing them.

Comment: They're actually quite easy to pronounce, for example the first word I got was "viketuziwo" `:P`

Comment: @Doorknob maybe it's just my luck. I keep getting 'words' like "qijepyjyga". My computer's attempts to pronounce them make up for it though :)

Comment: I just had a lot of fun doing `python grc.py | say` on my machine. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby: 56 characters

```ruby
([v=%w(a e i o u y),[*?a..?z]-v]*5).map{|a|$><<a.sample}
```

Example outputs:

- itopytojog
- umapujojim
- ipagodusas
- yfoqinifyw
- ebylipodiz

Comment: `'aeiouy'.chars` would be one char shorter.

Comment: @Howard then the subtraction operator raises `TypeError: can't convert Enumerator into Array`

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry, forgot to mention that you need Ruby 2.0 for this trick.

Answer (score 6):

### APL (34)

```
,⍉↑(V[5?6])((⎕A~V←'AEIOUY')[5?20])
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 74

```
for(a=b=[];a++-5;)b+="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"[c=new Date*a%20]+"aeiouy"[c%6]
```

Does not generate all combinations, but I think that all consonants and vowel appear.

**JavaScript, 79**

```
for(a=b=[];a--+5;)b+="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"[c=Math.random()*20^0]+"aeiouy"[c%6]
```

More "random" version.

Comment: What's the `^0` for?

Comment: @Alpha `Math.random` gives a float, we need an integer. `^0` truncates the number

Comment: Clever trick. I haven't seen the `^` operator in JavaScript before and less heard about using it to truncate a float. Thanks!

Comment: @copy i like the use of `^`

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby: <s>70</s> 66 characters

```ruby
10.times{|i|$><<["aeiouy"*4,"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"][i%2][rand 20]}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -e '10.times{|i|$><<["aeiouy"*4,"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"][i%2][rand 20]}'
izogoreroz

bash-4.1$ ruby -e '10.times{|i|$><<["aeiouy"*4,"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"][i%2][rand 20]}'
onewijolen

bash-4.1$ ruby -e '10.times{|i|$><<["aeiouy"*4,"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"][i%2][rand 20]}'
amilyfilil
```

Comment: You can use `10.times` for one char less.

Comment: Also the question doesn't require that each letter must have same probability. `*10`->`*4`, skip `*3`, `rand 60`->`rand 20` and you have saved 3 chars.

Comment: Good catch on the rule, @Howard. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## **Processing, <strike>100</strike> <strike>99</strike> <strike>93</strike> 87**

```
int i=10;while(i-->0)"aeiouybcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz".charAt((int)random(i%2*6,6+i%2*i*2));
```

Upon closer inspection of the question, I see it doesn't require any output. I've adjusted this accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

### R: 105 characters

```
a=c(1,5,9,15,21,25)
l=letters
s=sample
cat(apply(cbind(s(l[-a],5),s(l[a],5)),1,paste,collapse=""),sep="")
```

Answer (score 4):

### J (51)

```
,|:>(<"1[5?6 20){&.>'aeiouy';'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'
```

Answer (score 4):

## Unix tools: 73 bytes

And not guaranteed running time :)

```
</dev/urandom grep -ao '[aeiouy][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]'|head -5|paste -sd ''
```

Only problem is that the generated string will start with a "vowel" every time.

(edit: changed  `' '` to `''` in the args of paste)
(another edit: removed -P from grep options, thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork))

Comment: Something could be fine tuned around the `grep` parameters. I got “of e� ap ag ak”.

Comment: Hmm... strange. I got nothing like that. I thought `-a` would be enough.

Comment: My test indicates that `-P` is the one. Seems the man warns about its highly experimental status with a reason. (`grep` 2.16) But anyway, it works fine without `-P`.

Comment: You are right thank you, I didn't consider that. I don't even know why I used `-P` in the first place. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: By the way, `tr -d \\n` is shorter for joining the lines.

Comment: yes, but it also removes the last '\n' messing up bash prompt :)

Comment: Doh. Indeed. And the “grep: write error” gets concatenated with the output. :(

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fRj8ltUy/tCgxLyU/VyG9KLVAQTcxX0EpOik5JS09I0s3r0C3pKy8oio2OjE1M7@0MlapJiM1MUVB17SmqFhBN93g/38A) with a few optimisations (and a lot faster)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP 79 bytes

```
<?for($c=bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz,$v=aeiouy;5>$i++;)echo$c[rand()%20],$v[rand()%6];
```

Fairly concise.

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript, 85

```
for(r=Math.random,s="",i=5;i--;)s+="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"[20*r()|0]+"aeiouy"[6*r()|0]
```

If run from the console, output is shown. Explicit display would add `alert(s)` at 8 chars, still shorter than the other JS solutions.

Thanks C5H8NNaO4 and Howard!

Comment: Nice one, save a character by removing the last ';'

Comment: Instead of `~~(###)` you can write `###|0` which saves 4 chars.

Answer (score 3):

**Java AKA the most verbose language ever created, 176** 
with help of Doorknob, Daniero and Peter Taylor (thanks guys!)

```
class w{public static void main(String[]a){int i=11;while(--i>0)System.out.print((i%2==0?"aeiouy":"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz").charAt(new java.util.Random().nextInt(6+(i%2)*14)));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
    class w {

        public static void main(String[] a) {
            int i = 11;
            while (--i > 0) {
                System.out.print((i % 2 == 0 ? "aeiouy" : "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz").charAt(new java.util.Random().nextInt(6 + (i % 2) * 14)));
            }
     }
```

}

Comment: Suggested improvements: Change `String a[]` to `String[]a` (-1 characters), change `w W = new w();` to `w W=new w();` (-2 characters)

Comment: Suggestions: Let the word always start on a consonant (or wovel); no need to randomize this when the question doesn't mention it! So, skip the boolean `f` and use `i%2` instead. Also, the `for` loop can be shortened, and you can put both the strings inside the conditional operator (also,no need for parens here), and use the `charAt` on the outside. Here's the whole thing, **195 CHARS, 38 SAVED**: `import java.util.*;class w{public static void main(String[]a){Random r=new Random();for(int i=0;++i<11;)System.out.print((i%2>0?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":"aeiouy").charAt(r.nextInt(6+(i%2)*14)));}}`

Comment: Continuing @Daniero's simplification: 1) do not declare a variable for `Random`; 2) remove the parenthesis from the formula. 183 characters: `import java.util.*;class w{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;++i<1100;)System.out.print((i%2>0?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":"aeiouy").charAt(new Random().nextInt(6+i%2*14)));}}`.

Comment: “Java AKA the most verbose language ever created” – Ever tried [Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/)? ;-)

Comment: @manatwork, don't forget to remove the import once you've got it down to being used only in one place.

Comment: Possibly controversial suggestion: One could squeeze a few more characters out of it by insisting that the program has to be run with two command line arguments (that should be counted in the character total of course), namely `aeiouy` and `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz`. This minimizes the overhead of the strings as you don't need the `"`'s anymore, and you can access them with `a[i%2]` (`a` is already defined in the boilerplate code). 142+20(?) chars: `class w{public static void main(String[]a){int i=11;while(--i>0)System.out.print(a[i%2].charAt(new java.util.Random().nextInt(6+(i%2)*14)));}}`

Comment: @Daniero, why only +20? Shouldn't that be +6+20? And no idea why you (and anakata) insist on the parenthesis around i%2. Its priority is higher than the preceding addition's anyway. http://pastebin.com/5reTnRDL

Comment: @manatwork, 26 yes off course, I did this very rapidly, just vaguely remembered that some string in there was 20 chars long (my native language's alphabet is longer than the English one, so 26 doesn't mean that much to me) ;) The parenthesis can obviously go, nice. The first time I used the expression 14*(i%2), in which the parens must stay, didn't think off switching 14 to the back. Last time I just copied the whole thing from anakata's answer to show the `a[i%2]` trick, didn't think about the parenthesis any longer.

Comment: @manatwork maybe we like lisp ?? ok, sorry, gonna take those parenthesis out when I get home from work

Comment: I know it's been 6 years (lol), but you can golf it to 163 bytes by changing `int i=11;while(--i>0)` to `for(int i=11;--i>0;)`; `i%2==0` to `i%2<1` and `new java.util.Random().nextInt(6+(i%2)*14)` to `(int)(Math.random()*(6+i%2*14))`. EDIT: Actually, 160 bytes like this: `class W{public static void main(String[]a){for(int i=11,t;--i>0;System.out.print((i%2<1?"aeiouy":"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz").charAt(t*=Math.random())))t=6+i%2*14;}}`, or an additional -3 with Java 8+ changing `class W{public static void main` to `interface W{static void main`. [**Try it online.**](https://tinyurl.com/y3u28opl)

Answer (score 3):

**Objective-C, 129**

```
main(){int i=10;while(i-->0)printf("%c",[(i%2==0)?@"aeiouy":@"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"characterAtIndex:arc4random()%(6+(i%2)*14)]);}
```

With the help of Daniero

(I love to use the *tends to* operator (-->)

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 100 Characters

```
<?while($i<6){echo substr('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz',rand(0,20),1).substr('aeiouy',rand(0,5),1);$i++;}?>
```

Comment: acually I think that's 100 chars long

Answer (score 3):

### APL  <del>30</del> 26

```
,('EIOUY'∪⎕A)[6(|,+)⍪5?20]
```

Explanation is very similar to the past version below, just reordered a bit to golf the solution.

Note: ⎕IO is set to 0

---

```
('EIOUY'∪⎕A)[,6(|,(⍪+))5?20]
```

Explanation:

```
'EIOUY'∪⎕A    puts vowels in front of all letters.
5?20            for the indexes we start choosing 5 random numbers between 0 and 19
6(|,(⍪+))        then we sum 6 and the random numbers, convert to 5x1 matrix (⍪), add a column before this one containing 6 modulo the random numbers. 
                [[[ this one can be rewritten as: (6|n) , ⍪(6+n)  for easier understanding]]]
,6(|,(⍪+))5?20  the leading comma just converts the matrix to a vector, mixing the vowel and consonants indexes.
```

[Tryapl.org](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2395IO%u21900%20%u22C4%20%2C%28%27EIOUY%27%u222A%u2395A%29%5B6%28%7C%2C+%29%u236A5%3F20%5D&run)

Comment: `('AEIOUY'∪⎕A) ≡ (∪'AEIOUY',⎕A)` but it's one byte shorter.

Comment: Deferring 'A' to `⎕A` saves another byte: `,('EIOUY'∪⎕A)[6(|,+)⍪5?20]`

Comment: Nice! down to 26. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 26 characters

```
J-G"aeiouy"VT=k+kOJ=J-GJ;k
```

[You can try it in the online compiler here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J-G%22aeiouy%22VT%3Dk%2BkOJ%3DJ-GJ%3Bk&debug=0)

Someone posted a very similar challenge but it was closed after I had made a solution. I didn't realize it, but this question actually predates the creation of Pyth. Anyway, here is the breakdown:

```
J                             Set string J equal to:
  G                            the entire alphabet (lowercase, in order)
 - "aeiouy"                    minus the vowels
           VT                 For n in range(1, 10):
             =k                   Set string k to:
                k                  k (defaults to empty string)
               + OJ                plus a random character from J
                   =J             Set J to:
                      G            the entire alphabet
                     - J           minus J
                        ;     End of loop
                         k    print k
```

Every time the loop is run, J switches from being a list of consonants to a list of vowels. That way we can just pick a random letter from J each time.
There may be a way to initialize J in the loop or remove the explicit assignments from the loop, but I have not had success with either yet.

Comment: Bumping old questions is generally considered fine. However, when you use a language newer than the question (I created Pyth in 2014) you should note this in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I didn't realize that Pyth was created after this question and I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

## K, 40 bytes

```
,/+5?/:("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz";"aeiouy")
```

`5?"abc"` will generate 5 random letters from the given string.

`5?/:` will generate 5 random letters from each of the strings on the right, producing two lists.

`+` transposes those two lists, giving us a list of tuples with one random character from the first list and then one from the second list.

`,/` is "raze"- fuse together all those tuples in sequence.

K5 can do this in 33 bytes by building the alphabet more cleverly and then using "except" (`^`) to remove the vowels, but K5 is much too new to be legal in this question:

```
,/+5?/:((`c$97+!26)^v;v:"aeiouy")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <del>104</del> 87

```javascript
a="";for(e=10;e--;)a+=(b=e&1?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz":"aeiouy")[0|Math.random()*b.length]
```

*golfed a whole lot of simple unnecessary stuff, still not nearly as nice as [copys' one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11897)*

*Oh, and that one just opped up during golfing: **"dydudelidu"***

<sub>Now I tried one using the 2 characters at once approach. Turns out it's almost the same as copys' second one, so I can't count it, also at 79.
`a="";for(e=5;e--;)a+="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"[m=0|20*Math.random()]+"aeiouy"[m%6]`</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## C: 101

```
main(){int x=5;while(x-->0){putchar("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"[rand()%21]);putchar("aeiou"[rand()%5]);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
Ḍ;Ẉṣᵐzh₅c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy/@KJnOKIp@KGsOKCgeG6ieKKpf/huIw74bqI4bmj4bWQemjigoVj//8)

Gives output as a list of letters through the output variable.

```
   ṣ         Randomly shuffle
 ;  ᵐ        both
Ḍ            the consonants without y
  Ẉ          and the vowels with y,
     z       zip them into pairs,
      h₅     take the first five pairs,
             and output
        c    their concatenation.
```

Answer (score 2):

## ["Random Word Generator"](https://bigyihsuan.github.io/phono-word-gen/), 70 +2 = 72 bytes

```
C=b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x z
V=a e i o u y
syllable:$C$V
```

Set minimum and maximum number of syllables settings to `5` (which I'm counting as flags, so 1 byte each).

This is written in a (WIP) tool I wrote for generating words from a sound inventory for conlanging (making constructed languages). I made the tool due to the other word generators (that I know of) having flaws (in my opinionated opinion).

The above code sets two categories `C` and `V`, and defines a syllable as a `C` followed by a `V`. The flags (minimum and maximum syllables) define how many syllables will be generated for a given word.

#### No changed settings, 86 bytes

```
C=b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x z
V=a e i o u y
syllable:$C$V$C$V$C$V$C$V$C$V
```

Due to a bug in my implementation, this solution is extremely slow due to the large syllable size.

Answer (score 1):

**F#**, 166 characters

```
open System;String.Join("",(Random(),"aeiouybcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz")|>(fun(r,s)->[0..5]|>List.collect(fun t->[s.Substring(6+r.Next()%20,1);s.Substring(r.Next()%6,1)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 83 bytes

```
cat(outer((l<-letters)[a<-c(1,5,9,15,21,25)],l[-a],paste0)[sample(1:120,5)],sep="")
```

Generate all possible vowel-consonant sequences in a matrix, then randomly sample 5 of them, yielding a 10-letter word.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
5FžPΩ?žOΩ?
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f1O3ovoBzK@2P7vMHkv//AwA) or [output \$n\$ amount of random words](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/e/239Tt6L6Acyvtj@7zB5L/aw9ts/9vaAAA).

**Explanation:**

Pretty straight-forward:

```python
5F      # Loop 5 times:
  žP    #  Push string "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"
    Ω   #  Pop and push a random character from this string
     ?  #  Output it without newline
  žOΩ?  #  Do the same with string "aeiouy"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>57</s> <s>47</s> <s>46</s> 54 bytes

```
{`prng@0;,/{(1?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"),1?"aeiouy"}'!5}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOKCjKS3cwsNbRr9YwtFdKSk5JS8/Iys7JzSsoLCouKSuvqFLS1AHKJKZm5pdWKtWqK5rWcnGlRccCAIl/FGE=)

*Down 1 byte thanks to ngn*

Takes inspiration from the [PHP answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11882/107017). This one now outputs random words at each call, with the cost of 8 extra bytes.

Explanation:

```
{`prng@0;,/{(1?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"),1?"aeiouy"}'!5} Main function. Takes no input
                                                   !5  Generate a array with range from 0 to 4 ([0..4])
                                                  '    For each number...
           {                                     }     Execute a function that...
            (1?"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz"),1?"aeiouy"      Chooses one random consonant, followed by one random vowel
         ,/                                            Joined each of these strings together
 `prng@0;                                              Use current time to set state of randomness (Thus allow random words)
```

Comment: `""/` -> `,/`  ⁣⁣

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>20</s> 17 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;`Á<`
5Æö iCkU ö
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=O2CMwTxgCjXG9iBpQ2tVIPY)

Note that there is an unprintable character in front of the `Á`

```
;          # C = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
 `ŒÁ<`     # U = "oueayi"

5Æ         # Do this 5 times:
  ö        #  Pick a random letter from U
    i      #  Prepend: 
     CkU   #   Remove the letters in U from C
         ö #   Get a random letter from the result

-P         # Print all the pairs with no separator
```

Comment: [19 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=O2CMwTxgCjXG9iBpQ2tVIPbDrA). And you can save another 2 bytes with the `-P` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Cü_èyi%Ã®ö5ÃÕ
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=O0P8X%2bh5aSXDrvY1w9U)

```
;Cü_èyi%Ã®ö5ÃÕ
;C                 :Lowercase alphabet
  ü                :Group by
   _               :Passing each character through the following function
    è              :  Count
     yi%           :    "y" prepended with "%", giving the Japt RegEx "%y"=/[aeiouy]/i
        Ã          :End grouping
         ®         :Map
          ö5       :  5 random characters
            Ã      :End map
             Õ     :Transpose
                   :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 89 bytes

```javascript
for(;a=Math.random().toString(36).match(/([bcdfghj-np-tvwxz][aeiouy]){5}/g),!a;);print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctNDsIgEAbQs7ibSYQujMaEeARXLpsuPqkFmhQIHfEvnh19@zejYrUlZFH12NqUChmczhCvC@KYFmIt6SIlREe7A@sFYj111F/tODk/q5iV1MfzPfS4hXR/DfzZfzvH2w0Mm/yPQuDWfg)

`/g` makes the result without an extra appearance of pair

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
5ıkykz,€ɼ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTUlQzQlQjFreWt6JTJDJUUyJTgyJUFDJUM5JUJDJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JmZsYWdzPUo=)

##### Explanation

```python
5ıkykz,€ɼ  # Implicit input
5ı         # Repeat 5 times:
  ky  , ɼ  #  Random vowel
    kz €ɼ  #  Random consonant
           # Join into a string
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 8 bytes

```
k¹k∪"5ƈ∩
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzIiwiIiwia8K5a+KIqlwiNcaI4oipIiwiIiwiIl0=)

```
    "    # Pair
k¹       # Consonants
  k∪     # And vowels
     5ƈ  # Choose 5 random items from each
       ∩ # Interleave
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Øy,ØYẊ€Zs5ḢŒl
```

**Explanation:**

```
Øy,ØYẊ€Zs5ḢŒl
Øy,ØY         Makes a list of two lists of characters: [[list-of-vowels-with-y], [list-of-consonants-without-y]]
     Ẋ€       Shuffle €ach.
       Z      Zip those two lists together. [[random-vowel, random-consonant],...]
        s5    Split them into chunks of five (because each pair contains two letters, this splits them into chunks of 10 letters)
          Ḣ   Take the list of 5 pairs.
           Œl Make each of the characters in it lowercase
              Implicit concatenation and print.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9qZWxsef//w5h5LMOYWeG6iuKCrFpzNeG4osWSbP//)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 63 bytes

```c
c;f(n){for(n=10;n;81192%c-n&1||putchar(c,n--))c=97+clock()%26;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcFNDoJADAbQPadgg2kjTRgWKmk4zORLBoxYDD9hAVzd6nuQDnCHJjLe0ziRtaFS00cITV1A7BKO47Mu6ONEKE2EGW1zv2IY8SIu6pue/o5PI873LP9LxJqd/kUaYje7bD8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) `--braceccl`, 57 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKKQVJSYnJqcnPO/OKM0TUE3z1TBRiM1OSNfoTopOSUtPSNLN69At6SsvKKqtjoxNTO/tLK2pqhYwUDBUBNE66Yb/P8PAA)

```zsh
shuf -n5 <(echo {bcdfghj-np-tvwxz}{aeiouy}|rs 0 1)|rs -g0
```

Alternates: [67b using `jot`](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/K79EQbdIQTdZwdJCIVGhqqaoWMFAwUhBN92gJr0otUBBKTouMTUzv7QyNhpKK9VkpCamKOiagtQC1f3/DwA) ;
[77b using arrays](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKKQVJSYnJqcnPO/zDYxNTO/tFIh2VajOik5JS09I0s3r0C3pKy8oqpWk6sotSA1sUTBVKGgKDOvJE1BJTnaUDvI0c/F31fVyCBWpQzBNYv9/x8A)