# Write some Random English

Tags: code-golf, random

## Your Goal:

Given an odd integer input `n` greater than 1, generate a random *English word* of length `n`. An English word is one in which the **odd** (1-based) indices are **consonants** and the **even** (1-based) **indices** are vowels, the vowels being `aeiou`.

### Random

For the purposes of this challenge, you are to sample from the vowels and consonants uniformly, with replacement. In other words, each possible English word must be equally likely to appear as an output.

## Example Inputs/Outputs

```
3 -> bab, tec, yiq
5 -> baron, nariz, linog
7 -> murovay, fanafim
```

**Winner:**

Winner is the Lowest Byte Count.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I don't really understand the challenge here.  Maybe the sandbox (linked on the right), would be a good place to get feedback.

Comment: Are we making a function that generates the words? Or should the program simply generate them when run?

Comment: Hi there. I've voted to close this as needing additional clarity, but do not fret when this gets closed! It's tough to get a challenge specified up to our standards the first few times you come up with one, so we have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for you to get feedback on them before they come to the main site. Hope you enjoy your time here, and happy golfing!

Comment: Be sure to specify what you mean by [_random_](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/36398). Also, how is the output size specified? Is it also random?

Comment: Some questions for clarification: (1) does this take input, and if so, what is the input and how exactly does it affect the output? (2) What is meant by random? Do we select vowels and consonants with replacement, so `bab` and `babab` would each be possible, or without? Does each word generated this way have equal chance of being generated, or does each word have to have a non-zero probability of appearing, or is there some other specific, well-defined distribution you're looking for? I see Luis has asked basically the same questions, but you have not yet addressed them in any way.

Comment: @Giuseppe no extra details needed... Thats what I meant. I wanted to see who could create vowel and non vowel random words in the least amount of bytes. See the number one answer, they did it right.

Comment: We have [some guidelines](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2020/a-better-help-center) on things to include in your challenge. If you'd like, I'd be happy to edit this question up to our standards (with your input, of course) so we can get this re-opened and get some upvotes on it! I haven't downvoted it because I think it's a good challenge; it just needs some refinement and it should get a decent amount of attention.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited it (and voted to re-open), please make edits to it as you feel appropriate!

Comment: [Reminds me of this challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11877/generate-a-pronounceable-word) Main difference being that this takes length as input. Actually, I'm not sure if that makes this a dupe or not.

Comment: @ValueInk He wants pronouncable words, and y itsnt a vowel, but he includes it anyways. Your able to merge AEIOU and its actually a pronouncable sound, with Y it adds an extra sectional sound, its incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ØḄØẹḂ?X)
```

*-1 byte thanks to @Steffan*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIc7WoDErp0PdzTZR2j@///fFAA)

Explanation:

````
ØḄØẹḂ?X)  # main link taking an integer

       )  # over the list [1..n]
     ?    # if
    Ḃ     # n modulo 2 is truthy
ØḄ        # yield the consonants
  Øẹ      # otherwise the vowels
      X   # get a random letter from that
```
````

Comment: `ØḄØẹḂ?X)` for 8 bytes by using `Ḃ` (modulo 2) instead of checking for divisibility by 2.

Comment: Another interesting 8-byter with `ƭ` (tie): `ØḄØẹ2ƭX)`

Comment: @Steffan Thank you! Didn't know `Ḃ` was a thing

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <strike>14</strike> 11 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

```
EžN¸žMšNèΩJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9vc2FiaWX//0XFvk7CuMW@TcWhTsOozqlK//83)

Comment: `¸ì` can be `š`, `.R` can be `Ω`, and the `}` can be removed before the join.

Comment: oh wow, thank you! @KevinCruijssen

Answer (score 5):

## [Plain English](https://osmosianplainenglishprogramming.blog/), 485 bytes

```
To add any vowel to a string:
Pick a letter of the alphabet.
If the letter is any vowel, append the letter to the string; exit.
Repeat.

To add any consonant to a string:
Pick a letter of the alphabet.
If the letter is any consonant, append the letter to the string; exit.
Repeat.

To make a random string given a length:
If a counter is past the length, exit.
Add any consonant to the random string.
If the counter is past the length, exit.
Add any vowel to the random string.
Repeat.
```

What better way to write some random English than by using Plain English? I have applied a moderate level of golfing to this code; certain things could be shortened, but it would make this less legible, which would be a shame.

The reason I have defined three routines is because nested loops are forbidden in Plain English, so inner loops must be factored into separate routines.

Parameters and local variables are written as "a string" or "a length" (for example). These are subsequently referred to as "the string" and "the length." If you need to refer to more than one string, you could for example introduce "another string" and refer to it with "the other string." You may also name them whatever you want: "a random string" and refer to it either as "the random" or "the random string."

All arguments are passed by reference; even numbers. To output from a routine, you just modify the arguments. Then you simply refer to the object returned by the routine in the same way as you refer to parameters. For example, to use the routine defined above to output a random English word, you could:

```
To run:
Start up.
Make a random string given 5.
Write the random string on the console.
Wait for the escape key.
Shut down.
```

"To run:" is a special routine that signifies the starting point of the program. When added to the other three routines, this results in a program which will show something similar to the following when compiled and run:

[image: Output of the program showing "JAWEF"]

Comment: I cant tell if this is a joke or not but I love it lol

Comment: @MisterSirCode That was my first reaction too! But after reading Plain English's compiler, which is written in Plain English, I was quickly disabused of that notion!

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 69 bytes

```perl
say map{([a,e,i,o,u],[grep!/[eiou]/,b..z])[$_%2][rand$_%2*16+5]}1..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7GgWiM6USdVJ1MnX6c0Vic6vSi1QFE/OjUzvzRWXydJT68qVjNaJV7VKDa6KDEvBcTSMjTTNo2tNdTTs7H7/9/QwPBffkFJZn5e8X9dX1M9A0MDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 89 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,b)=>(b?"aeiou":"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwyxz")[~~(Math.random()*(b?5:21))]+(--n?f(n,!b):"")
```

[Try it online! (includes tests)](https://tio.run/##ZYxbCsIwEACvsgY/djUtqIhYUE/gCUqh6SOtGrPaxvooiofwhF6k6rd/A8PMVjWqTqvNwXmWs7zr9AKtTGixxGQlVL7hkwhEkma6KLc7s7eHY1W75ny93ASFjweulSv9StmM90iDbzQNxiOiaIieZ1f6O@slFAhBneYKMGVbOzDAGsKJhKmEmYR5RPATbHLfcIFxvzV3eD9fS@i3Gg3d5R/E1H0A)

Takes `n` as length and `b` as whether to return vowel or consonant, default consonant.

Returns consonant or vowel based on `b`, decrements `n` and recurses with opposite `b` value.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÇÅφ⌠↑Ñ°↕Yx
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=808fedf418a5f8125978&i=7)

## Explanation

```
FVcVv2l@_@L

F           In range 1 to the input, do this ...
 Vv         Vowels
   Vc       Consonants
     2l     Wrap the two inside a list
       @    Index the constructed list into the counter
            Note that the counter starts at 1,
            so this picks the constants list
            before the vowels list.
        _@  Index by the current counter
            (Stax doesn't have random number support)
          L Wrap the whole stack into a list
```

Comment: Wow, nice job on this one

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 36 bytes

```
,{['aeiou'.123,97>^]\2%=.,rand=}%''+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPlv/l@nOlo9MTUzv1Rdz9DIWMfS3C4uNsZI1VZPpygxL8W2VlVdXfv/fwA)

Comment: You can save some bytes by using ['aeiou'.123,97>^] instead of your long string. Generates the characters 98-123, then removes the vowels. Plus, they're in two distinct arrays too, which saves you a bunch too. the string and 21/ can be removed, meaning you're down 31 chars and up 18, netting 13.

,{['aeiou'.123,97>^]\2%=.,rand=}%''+

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 76 bytes

Basic recursive function that adds a consonant and a vowel each time until there's only one character left, at which point it adds just the consonant.

```ruby
f=->n{[*?b..?z].grep(/[^eiou]/).sample+(n<2?'':'aeiou'.chars.sample+f[n-2])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6vOlrLPklPz74qVi@9KLVAQz86LjUzvzRWX1OvODG3ICdVWyPPxsheXd1KPREkoa6XnJFYVAyTTIvO0zWK1az9b6xXXALUbmioY6SpkJKvUJNZw6WgUFBaUqyQFp0Zq4NEcqXmpfwHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 83 bytes

```py
lambda n:[*map(choice,["bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy","aeiou"]*n)][:n]
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYw9DsIgGEB3T0GIAzSYaCfTxFM4Ygf6Q_m0fCBStV7FhcTonbyNmjq94b28-8uP0ThMD73ZPYeoF-v3tle2ahTBQmZWeVYbB3UrJK3qRndmf-gt-mM4xfPlehupoKoFN9AyQ17KAsuZDs6SoLD5Aqx3IWb_9Vy7QIAA_nTXspXIlyLnhQ-AkYHQDDif2pQmfgA)

Outputs a list of characters.

This is conceptually the same as [grc's answer for "Generate a pronounceable word"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11879/113573), since the questions are almost identical.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 9 bytes

```
⟑₂¨ikvk¹℅
```

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwi4p+R4oKCwqhpa3ZrwrnihIUiLCIiLCI3Il0=)

Explanation:

```
⟑          # Map over the range 1 to n
 ₂¨i       # If even:
    kv     #   Push the string "aeiou"
           # Otherwise:
      k¹   #   Push the lowercase consonants
        ℅  # Get a random character from the top of the stack
           # Concatenate the character list into a string with the s flag
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 12 bytes

```
RC*[.CZVW]Ha
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJSQypbLkNaVlddSGEiLCIiLCIiLCI3Il0=)

#### Explanation

This should be 11 bytes; the `.` is a no-op to work around a bug in the current language version.

```
RC*[CZVW]Ha
   [    ]    List containing:
    CZ         Lowercase consonants
      VW       Lowercase vowels
          a  Command-line argument
         H   Take that many elements (cycling the list as necessary)
RC*          Random choice from each
```

---

I also found several 13-byte solutions:

```
RC{VW::CZ}M,a
RC[CZVW]@_M,a
LaORC(VW::CZ)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup>93</sup> 89 bytes

```bash
v=aeiou]
until tr -dc a-z</dev/urandom|head -c$1|grep -E "^[^$v([$v[^$v)*[$v?$";do
:
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqiYPK/zDYxNTO/NJarNK8kM0ehpEhBNyVZIVG3ykY/JbVMv7QoMS8lP7cmIzUxRUE3WcWwJr0otUBB11VBKS46TqVMI1qlDERragEZ9ipK1in5XFZcKfl5qf//AwA)

A full command line program.

It generates random lowercase alpha strings of the required size in a loop until we find one matching the pattern `^<vowel>(<cons><vowel>)*<cons>?`.

Answer (score 2):

### [D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(programming_language)), 124 bytes

```
auto f(int n){string s;for(import std;n;n--,s~=n%2?"aeiou"[uniform(0,5)]:"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"[uniform(0,20)]){}return s;}
```

I'm not very good at code golf (but trying to get better) so this can probably be improved a lot

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY7LDoIwEEXX8hWTJiRtBIMkbqjEDzEu0AKOylTbgg@Cv47FjS5uzuYk56oRm6s2DqxTCz/Ucixap6HiSA5I9NYZpBqsrLThP1mSpDiO7DunMN2wokTdsm1L6LWGJ9FK7DK2P6iqPp7Ol4auN2Ndd388X/9Wmoid6AdTutaQbwxjp1FBUyBxAX0AAN@sv4KQw1J6rCFNJs5zSEUwuxt0ZXUhzkKVQWhZBBhN94WQwTB@AA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Unfortunately we don't have a *Tips for Golfing in D* page, but it's nice to see someone using a language not regularly used on our site!

Comment: You might want to add a [Try it online](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsIwEEX3/YqhICTSSim40CB@iHQRk9ZG7aQm0/oo9ddjBBdu7upcztHBdL11BMq6euVJq@8YK4IcyELDDBIgnzw5gyfworGO/S4RFCgwzzP/3uGi3KeyNnZIDwOaiHWsyNa82qZHpZtTe75cO@xvztN4fzxf/1RZ8IpPs6tpcBgdcxit0dBJg4zDlABAH/XUMCU9AVOtdEse4zaci2QOHw "D – Try It Online") link so others can test your code. Note:  I don't know D and I'm probably doing this wrong.

Comment: [Golfed off a few bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7LCsIwFET3/YpLQUhqKyq4kOCXlC5i0kfU3tTktj5K/fUYwc0shjkzo4PpB@sIlHX1xpNWPzFWBDmShYYZJEA@e3IGW/CisY79kRgUKPznVKayNnZM8/SsdNN2l@utx@HuPE2P5@udViWu9lU5ool0z7b57pCxaPH1gVcci0K4mkaHsX4JkzUaemmQcZgTABjiMjVMSU/AVCddxuOvI@ciWcIX). Idk what the issue with garbage bytes being appended is...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't rely on counting backwards since the vowels/consonants will swap depending on the parity of the input. You can fix this by changing `s~=...` to `s=...~s`. You can also combine the strings and indexing for [112 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYzNCoJAFEb3PsVFCGYqI4UWMfQk0cIax245d2x@tBJ79UlX0eKDjwPnyBjL4A0ohuSB@OC8RarBCWUsQ90a68F5KUhwd0jPF6nq6@3eaGof1vmuf77eZYUmpMdAODmaZRktimWRr4t8Nb8dP32csJUPlqbuGH/VzTQ0IukMStAlEuMwJADQW/RVQ0yxPefin@TbGY3xCw)

Comment: the issue with garbage characters was since you were using cast(char*) to convert to a C string when passing to printf. you have to use toStringz (or the better solution is just to use the write/writeln function from std.stdio)

Comment: also parity isn't an issue since the challenge specification says that the input number will always be odd

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `rṀs`, 8 bytes

```
ƛkvk⁰"i℅
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJy4bmAcyIsIiIsIsaba3Zr4oGwXCJp4oSFIiwiIiwiNCJd)

Fun

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `pair-rocket sequences.repeating`, 62 bytes

```factor
[ "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"=> "aeiou"swap cycle [ random ] map ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RYwxDoIwFEB3TvHTHTcTo5FR4-JinAhD_XywUtryW0S8iguLDt6I22hCjNNL3kve41VIDJaHcXM87PbbJTipOGaLFQWoiA1p8NS0ZJD8jMmRDMqUwNLktv4nUBZWUTR_tqGIF2OSgjhhXpTnS6Vr4xr24drd-rtYJyAkKdsK30kH2KMmSH-_DOqvzKbLG6XW0LEKNIlhmPgB)

```
                                   ! 5
"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"=> "aeiou"  ! 5 { "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" "aeiou" }
swap                               ! { "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" "aeiou" } 5
cycle                              ! { "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" "aeiou" "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" "aeiou" "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz" }
[ random ] map                     ! "furom"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
J"aeiou"smO?%d2J-GJ
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=J%22aeiou%22smO%3F%25d2J-GJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A5%0A7&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
J"aeiou"smO?%d2J-GJ  | Full code
J"aeiou"smO?%d2J-GJQ | with implicit variables
---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
J"aeiou"             | J = "aeiou"
         m         Q | For each d in [0...input):
          O          |  Pick a random letter from
               J     |   J
           ?%d2      |   if d is even else
                -GJ  |    the lowercase alphabet minus J (i.e. the consonants)
        s            | Print the concatenated results
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>61</s> 58 bytes

```c
c;f(n){for(;n;4370%c-n&1&&putchar(c,n--))c=97+clock()%26;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHRCoJAEAXQd7/CF5cZckArWmToY5YLq5KNYUUP4q83eg6kB9yhmYzXPC@kptdLbCqIhTaE1/eDIS2E2kSYce/iCdOMB3F1vunmzzQacbkW5SFTZC02/yNPqX@7/HY)

-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat!!

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 67 bytes

```
{$!=<a e i o u>;({(('a'..'z')∖$!,$!)[$++%2].pick}...*)[^$_].join}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WkXR1iZRIVUhUyFfodTOWqNaQ0M9UV1PT71KXfNRxzQVRR0VRc1oFW1tVaNYvYLM5OxaPT09Lc3oOJX4WL2s/My82v8FpSUKaRoq8ZoKFRUKxgpp@UUKxjoKpjoK5v8B)

- The vowels are stored in `$!`, one of just two special global variables that don't need to be declared.
- `{ ... } ... *` is a lazy, infinite list, where the code between the braces generates each successive element.
- `('a' .. 'z') ∖ $!` are the consonants.  That `∖` isn't a backslash, it's the Unicode `SET MINUS` character.
- `(('a' .. 'z') ∖ $!, $!)[$++ % 2]` alternately chooses the consonants and vowels on each iteration of the generator.  The anonymous state variable `$` counts how many iterations there have been so far, and the `% 2` reduces that to the alternating sequence `0, 1, 0, 1, ...`.
- `.pick` chooses a random vowel or consonant.
- `[^$_]` takes a number of elements from the sequence equal to the argument passed to the function.
- `.join` joins those elements into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) `--braceccl`, 67 bytes

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FcWxDkAwFAXQ3VfcwcDwEo3B4md4WiXSNtoaVL@9GE7O7XXxMlgXMJ8TS@ajUk2bitdRgUwtMDaStUWaeVGr3sk4ChfdOU1yszE/p0cH0f7T2j0cA4hBtSi5Uug/w0cM5QU)

```zsh
shuf -n$1 <(echo {bcdfghj-np-tv-z}{aeiou}|rs 0 1)|rs -g0|cut -c -$1
```

Similar to the [pronounceable word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255756/15940) solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-mP`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;Ck%+Ugciv¹ö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW1Q&code=O0NrJStVZ2Npdrn2&input=Nw)

```
;Ck%+Ugciv¹ö     :Implicit map of each U in the range [0,input)
;C               :Lowercase alphabet
  k              :Remove
   %+            :  Append to "%"
     Ug          :  Index U into
       civ       :    "c" prepended with "v"
          ¹      :End remove ("%v"=/[aeiou]/gi "%c"=/[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]/gi)
           ö     :Random character
                 :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 148 bytes

```
import random
randomize()
proc x(y:int):string=
  let l="bcdfghjklmpqrstvwxyz";let a="auioe";for i in 0..y-1:result.add sample(if(i%%2)==0:l else:a)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc49DoIwGMbxnVO8ISEpgwSZTEkPU2kLr_YD26LAOdxcSIyDR_I2atDpyT_P8rvdLZpleQxRbXavK5re-QieW-FMsg7OkuRJ710DI5ko2pjTED3aliUAWkbQLN03QrXd4ahNf_Ihni_jNKf19-Qs5QM6mdbKeUBAC2VRTJst9TIMOhZcCAjc9FoSVASzrMoZK6kGqYOkPF9tT9l07gOofv03vwE)